# In a dataframe with pair-wise observations, I'd like to identify the observation in a pair with the earlier time stamp

Tags: r, datetime

Currently, I have a data frame containing several hundred pair-wise observations. Within these data there is a column of unique time stamps. My goal is to create a binary indicator that gives a value of 1 to the observation in a pair that has an earlier time stamp, and 0 to the other. Some example data is generated below:

```
# Create a vector of pair IDs
pair_ids <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5)

# Create a vector of observation IDs
obs_ids <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

# Create a vector of date/time values, including some missing values
date_times <- c("2023-03-27 10:00:00", "2023-03-27 10:15:00", "2023-03-27 11:00:00",
                "2023-03-27 11:15:00", "2023-03-27 12:00:00", NA, NA,
                "2023-03-27 13:00:00", NA, NA)

# Create a data frame with the three columns
df <- data.frame(pair_id = pair_ids, obs_id = obs_ids, date_time = as.POSIXct(date_times))
```

Because there are so many different pairs in my data, I need to find a way to accomplish this task programmatically. A couple of other details worth noting:

-In the situation where the timestamp is missing for just one of the observations in a pair (such as pairs #3 and #4 in the example data), I'd like to automatically give a value of 1 to the observation that has a non-missing time stamp.

-In the situation where both time stamps are missing in a pair (such as pair #5 in the example data), I'd like to give both observations in the pair a value of NA for the binary indicator.

Any and all help in determining the best way to go about this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `dplyr` and the `case_when()` function

```
df %>% 
  group_by(pair_id) %>% 
  mutate(indicator = case_when(date_time==min(date_time, na.rm=T) ~ 1,
                               TRUE ~ 0),
         indicator = case_when(sum(indicator)==0 ~ NA_real_,
                                   TRUE ~ indicator))
```